# What kind of output do you use to format a Yaml file with comments and dictionaries to get multiple different formats

Tags: python, dictionary, format, yaml, dump

I'm having problems finding information on how i can format what i need in order to save file data that has this type and formatting. Using comments within it as well as the dictionary.

I am not using pyYaml, just the standard yaml import.

```
#Frequency of updates in seconds ********LIVE-UPDATEABLE********
interval: 30

#Trading Dilution coins only
dilution_only: yes
#What coins do you want to trade with? ALL, Dilution, or Whitelist is EXAMPLE: ETH,XTZ,XLM
#coins_trading: ETH,ICX,LTC,MCO,ALGO,THETA,ETC,ENJ,XLM,PPT,XTZ,BAND
coins_trading: All
```

The above is what i'm trying to output to Yaml. I read this yaml in this manner, and i'm making some changes to some of the values and then plan to dump the entire file back to yaml.

Unless someone knows a way to change just the values to the keys in the yaml. That would be ideal.
If i could just change the Interval: 20 or one of the others. I haven't found a method or way of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

After looking into how to format this, i have found that Yaml does not work with commented lines, and it does not keep any structure as it functions like a dictionary. So lines are not ordered. That becomes something completely different.

Whereas i wasn't able to find formatting, updating a specific value is just like anything else.

```
import yaml
with open('file1', 'rU') as f:
    data = yaml.load(f)
data['devices'] = updated_data
with open('file1', 'w') as f:
    yaml.dump(data, f)
```

And this will allow you to change the value and write back to the yaml. The file will not go back in any certain order and if any comments were there originally, they will no longer be there.